# Change woocommerce product quantity input values from 'numbers' to 'seconds'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

My website makes videos for others. I need a little help, how can I change the product quantity input values from numbers like ''1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6....'' to seconds like "30s, 60s, 90s, 120s.......". The price will increase like normal 1 unit increment not 30 unit increment. For example, for 30 seconds one has to pay 20$, for 60s 40$, for 90s 60$. It would mean a lot if you could help me.

This is the picture of the input field:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think quantity is the answer here; I think it would be better to [add a new custom attribute](https://rextheme.com/create-woocommerce-custom-product-attributes/) for 'duration' to the product instead.  Then you can either use CSS/javascript to hide the quantity field, or just leave it if you prefer.